# How to execute a C++ program while including variables from the function within the terminal

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple program to calculate the hypotenuse length of a triangle. My question is, how can I give variables "side1" and "side2" values while executing the main function from the terminal? Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(int side1, int side2) {

    int c2 = (pow(side1, 2)) + (pow(side2, 2));
    
    std::cout << sqrt(c2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The function compiles without error, so normally I would execute the function from terminal using "./main.exe", but is there a way to pass values to variables side1 & side2 while executing? (ex: ./main.exe "5" "5"). I don't want to go the std::cin route because I already know how to do that. For the same reason, I don't want to assign values to the variables within the function (ex: int side1 {5};).

I don't know if this is possible to do or not, but sites like Leetcode have their functions set up this way, and I have no clue how they input values for test cases.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the main function can be

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

so you get an argument count and a "string" array. Note that `argv[0]` is the executable name, so `side1` would be `argv[1]` and `side2` is `argv[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted previously, your function signature for `main` is incorrect. The correct signature when you want to access command line arguments is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

`argc` is the count of arguments, the first being the name of the executable. `argv` is an array of those arguments. We can:

- Check that the right number of arguments have been passed in, and print an error if not.
- Use `std::atoi` to convert those inputs into ints, at which point we can use them as we please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: "<< argv[0] 
              << " val1 val2" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  auto v1 = std::atoi(argv[1]);
  auto v2 = std::atoi(argv[2]);

  std::cout << v1 << ", " << v2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Man, you beat me to it. You only forgot to `#include <cstdlib>` for `atoi()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the command line argument strings and convert them to integers. Alas, this does increase the complexity of your program a little if you want to catch errors.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int help()
{
  std::cerr << 
    "usage:\n"
    "  a.exe SIDE1 SIDE2\n\n"
    "Where SIDE1 and SIDE2 are integers.\n";
  return 1;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  int side1, side2;
  if (argc != 3) return help();
  try {
    side1 = std::stoi( argv[1] );
    side2 = std::stoi( argv[2] );
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    return help();
  }

  int c2 = side1*side1 + side2*side2;
  std::cout << std::sqrt( c2 ) << "\n";
}
```

You could leave a lot of that error checking out and just let the program crash without explanation, but IMHO it is always worth adding a usage clause to your program to help users (including yourself two months from now) figure out how to run the program.

Answer (score -1):

Your `main` signature is wrong. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function.

Comment: This seems much better suited to a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Chris How so? I'm not asking for more info nor suggesting improvements. I'm sort-of answering the question (even though it's basically just a link to the docs, instead of rewriting the explanation here).